# Access Report PageHeader not with GroupHeader

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm stuck with the following:

I have an Access2003 report "rptInvoices". 
Group levels are on CustomerID and PackingListID.

What I like to achieve is that every 2nd (or 3rd etc.) page of an invoice starts with a blank section (of say 9cm) at the top of the page. For this I would use an empty PageHeader section. If the Report's property PageHeader had a value like NotWithGroupHeaderX, this would be easy.

Since there isn't such a value: how can I hide the PageHeader on a report if there's a GroupHeader named grhCustomerID on that page?

Maybe I need a different approach, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

In the groupheader `format event` set the `pageheadersection.visible` to `true` so the page header prints for pages after the group header. In the group footer format event set the `pageheadersection.visible` to `false` so the page header does not print at the top of the next page which has the group header.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visible property of the page header in the format event of the group header.

```
Private Sub GroupHeader0_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Page()
    Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The code here is defective, as there is no If xxx Then statement at the beginning. One would assume you'd be testing something related to the page number.